# Transforming Ruby code from apple documentation (iPhoneOTAConfiguration) to Java

Tags: ios, ruby, jakarta-ee, encryption, mdm

I am working web application for iOS MDM.
In that, payload within mobileconfig is to be encrypted before sending to device.
Apple documentation givex following code as example, its in Ruby and working fine.
But, I am not able to implement the same in Java.

```
OpenSSL::PKCS7.encrypt(p7sign.certificates,
payload, OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher::new("des-ede3-cbc"),
OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)
```

Java code I used is as:

```
     PublicKey publicKey = x509cert.getPublicKey();
    //publinKey is key extracted from iOS device response stream

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    clearText = payloadContents.getBytes();
    //payloadContents are contents to be encrypyted
    cipherText = cipher.doFinal(clearText);
```

error after executing this is

java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)

Comment: Hi Nilesh, can you update your question to indicate what are the problems that you are having?

Comment: Chris thanks for quick reply...
I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

`PKCS7.encrypt` produces an EnvelopedData as specified in the [CMS RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-6.1). This is far more than simply encrypting the contents, it's a specification of an ASN.1 data structure that *involves* encryption.

To produce or decrypt something similar in Java, I'd recommend to use Bouncy Castle for the job, Javadocs for the relevant classes can be found [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/index.html) - pay specific attention to [CMSEnvelopedData](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSEnvelopedData.html) and friends.

The certificates that you passed in the Ruby call are used to create the RecipientInfo structures, something similar is possible using the [CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator.html) class.